# Using bootstrap in an html file served from the file system

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a web app that generates an html file (with js) that is served to browsers. I'd like users to be able to save this html file to their hard drive and view/run the file in the future without needing to go back to the web server (I know that this is an unusual requirement, but it is what I need).

I want to use bootstrap in the html file.

At first, I used the CDN links to bootstrap/jquery in the html file. It worked when viewing the page served from the web server but when you download and save the html file and then open it with the browser, chrome complains:

```
CSS stylesheet from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So, next I embedded the text of the minified version of bootstrap/jquery js and css. Although this made the html page pretty ugly, it did work when the page was served from the web server and when the saved page is opened in the browser from the file system.

However, if I use some glyphicons in the html file I get the error:

```
GET file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This, of course, is because of a relative file reference in the minified code:

```
url(../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf)
```

My question is, if I want the user to ***only*** have to download the single html file, how do I use the glyphicons in that html page?

If there is a better way of using bootstrap served from the file system than pasting the minified code in the html I am open to suggestions but I need the page to be served from the file system and work.

Comment: Does it have to be an html file they download?  Could it be another format?  There's really no way to do everything that you're asking without having them download the glyphicons font/svg.  You could probably make it available in other formats more easily.

Comment: When a user saves a html page using the built in `Save page as`, it does that automatically. What's stored on their PC is the html file and a folder, which holds the embedded files.

Comment: To only have the html file stored locally, did you try using absolute paths for your resource links, like: `url(http://www.server.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf)`?